# Chi Squared Distribution for Maximum Likelihood

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm beginning to work in bioinformatics and have come across some papers that utilize chi-squared distributions to make a maximum likelihood selection. Particularly in the area using 'amplicons'. I've reimplemented some algorithms in papers, but am unsure on how to use chi-squared to make a selection.

We have a matrix of data called our 'amplicon matrix', where columns are 'amplicons' and the data is a rna read, and a corresponding frequency matrix, containing the frequency of the items in the original matrix.

Here is a simplified example of the amplicon matrix as well as its corresponding frequency matrix.
$$
Amp = 
\begin{bmatrix}
'abab' &'cgcg' &'atat' \\
'baba' &'gtgt' &'tata' \\
'abab' &'gtgt' &'atta
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
F = 
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I need to select an initial column by two methods. The first is just by selecting one at uniform random. The chi-squared is where I'm confused. I'm using [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.chisquare.html) api and not totally sure of the degrees of freedom in the system. Is it just the rank of the frequency matrix? Additionally, how is a selection made based on the return value? Will it be guarenteed to correspond to a column index?

I apologize as it has been a while since I've taken any statistics, and will be refreshing my understanding in the fall.

Thank you.

EDIT: See comments.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the paper?  It is not at all clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2105/12/5 is the paper.

Comment: Having gone back to this it was quite a silly error on my part. The chi-squared _test_ was used for all pairs of columns. The column with the minimum sum of its tests is chosen as the guide distribution.